# If I include Java 8 in my Android app does that affect which devices it will work on?

Tags: java, android

I have just started trying to use the new Java Date Time API but when I went to import the classes like below,I get cannot resolve symbol.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
```

After a little bit of checking it I found that I need to enable java 8 (See below link).

https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html

I assume this link is still relevant, info gets out of date very quickly. I am using a AS 2.1.3 and JDK 1.8 both installed yesterday (Not sure if that tells you anything).

I just want to make sure that if I go through the process of doing this, will it affect older model devices (In this case I will use Joda Time) or i1s the Java version totally irrelevant to the device.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you'll only be able to use devices with Android N.

Comment: @chrylis Awesome thanks for that. I will stick with Joda time then. Appreciate the help

Comment: @chrylis Are you sure? That link in the question lists some of the features work on sdk 23 and lower. I think the Jack toolchain allows Java 8 to be used in any version

Comment: @cricket_007 He asked about the DateTime API specifically, which is a library issue, not a bytecode issue.

Answer (score 3):

## Back-ports

Much of the java.time functionality built into Java is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project.

### ThreeTenABP

Further adapted to Android in the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See: [*How to use ThreeTenABP in Android project*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

---

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is in maintenance mode. The team advises migration to the java.time classes.