# Joda DateTime what is the format?

Tags: java, jodatime

I was just reading the manual do Joda time and it gives the formatting for time object and I don't understand.

This is the link to the manual:

https://www.joda.org/joda-time/userguide.html

It gives the format as below

```
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime("2004-12-13T21:39:45.618-06:00");
```

We have: 2004-12-13 date, 06:00 time,

So what is T21:39:45.618-

Thanks for your help

Comment: From the very same doc : The initialization string must be in a format that is compatible with the ISO8601 standard. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: Or from the Javadoc for that constructor: "The String formats are described by ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser()." (And no, 06:00 isn't the time - it's a UTC offset, in this case -6 hours from UTC.)

Comment: Awesome thanks very much!

Comment: Offtopic, but why use joda time when there is JDK 8 time? Even the official joda time page says "Joda-Time is the de facto standard date and time library for Java prior to Java SE 8. Users are now asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310)."

Comment: @sashok_bg This was my question on stack overflow earlier today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39481128/if-i-include-java-8-in-my-android-app-does-that-affect-which-devices-it-will-wor